# Loading Scripts on specific component (Route) in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cdn

Is it possible to run html scripts in a specific React component only, instead of directly in index.html. The script loads a third party barcode scanner, which is only being used in one component, and therefore I want to avoid loading it for every component as this will slow the whole app down.

The npm module can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode but there is no documentation on how to import it, only to include it like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode@7.2.2-v2/dist/dbr.js" data-productKeys="LICENSE-KEY"></script> 
<script>
  let barcodeScanner = null;
        Dynamsoft.BarcodeScanner.createInstance({
            onFrameRead: results => {console.log(results);},
            onUnduplicatedRead: (txt, result) => {alert(txt);}
        }).then(scanner => {
            barcodeScanner = scanner;
            barcodeScanner.show();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this code but I have done some code like this.You can add script tag like this:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  loadScript() {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode@7.2.2-v2/dist/dbr.js";
    script.setAttribute("data-productKeys","LICENSE-KEY");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.append(script);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if(!YourComponent.bScriptLoaded){
      this.loadScript();  
      YourComponent.bScriptLoaded = true; 
    }
  }
}
```

This will add script tag in head tag and.And after that you can run your code in component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the React sample provided by Dynamsoft GitHub repository: https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode/tree/master/example/web/react

You can check out [Dynamsoft.js](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode/blob/master/example/web/react/src/Dynamsoft.js) and [HelloWorld.js](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dbr/javascript-barcode/blob/master/example/web/react/src/components/HelloWorld.js) to see how to import and use the module:

```js
import Dynamsoft from "dynamsoft-javascript-barcode";
Dynamsoft.BarcodeReader.engineResourcePath = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode@7.3.0-v1/dist/";
// Please visit https://www.dynamsoft.com/CustomerPortal/Portal/TrialLicense.aspx to get a trial license
Dynamsoft.BarcodeReader.productKeys = "PRODUCT-KEYS";
// Dynamsoft.BarcodeReader._bUseFullFeature = true; // Control of loading min wasm or full wasm.
export default Dynamsoft;
```

```js
import Dynamsoft from "../Dynamsoft";
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    ...
    let reader = this.reader = this.reader || await Dynamsoft.BarcodeReader.createInstance();
    ...
}
```

**Note**: This sample uses **7.3.0-v1**. **7.2.2-v2** does not support this usage.